# Append attributes to object from cropper plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object from cropper plugin about image attributes.

```
var data = $img.cropper('getData');
//Object {x: 90, y: 60, width: 720, height: 480, rotate: 0…}
```

Now i need to append more two values:

```
image_identifier = $('.image_identifier').text();
type_identifier = $('.type_identifier').text();
```

I tried this code:

```
data.push({'image_identifier':image_identifier, 'type_identifier':type_identifier});
```

But i am getting : `Uncaught TypeError: data.push is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container object is not an Array, so it has no array methods. What you should do is *extend* this object with new properties, the easiest way to do is using [$.extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/):

```
$.extend(data, {
  image_identifier: image_identifier,
  type_identifier: type_identifier
});
```

Note that you don't have to assign the result to anything; $.extend augments its first param, its target object.